When is $L^p(\mu)$ isomorphic to $L^p(\nu)$
Let $p \geq 1$, under which conditions on the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the spaces $L^p(\mu)$ and $L^p(\nu)$ isomorphic?

Assuming $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both separable, then they are isometrically isomorphic iff either both have a diffuse part or neither has a diffuse part, and both have the same number of atoms.

Thanks you very much @DavidGao ! Would you have a reference for this interesting result?

(If I’m not mistaken, the same should be the case if “isometrically isomorphic” is replaced by just “isomorphic”, as long as $p \neq \infty$. When $p = \infty$, again if both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are separable, and assuming $L^\infty(\mu)$ and $L^\infty(\nu)$ are both infinite-dimensional (so either they have diffuse parts or infinitely many atoms), then $L^\infty(\mu)$ and $L^\infty(\nu)$ are always isomorphic.)

I don’t really have a reference. The approach I have in mind is from an isometric isomorphism you can reconstruct the algebra structure of $L^\infty$. Then the number of atoms and whether a diffuse part exists can be retrieved from von Neumann algebra theory.

Okay I understand the idea. I will take time to fully understand. Thanks you again @DavidGao

@DavidGao I have seen you are a specialist of the Neuman algebra theory. Could you give me some precisions for "Then the number of atoms and whether a diffuse part exists can be retrieved from von Neumann algebra theory." (like some statements).  I know only a few on this theory, and I struggle to understand what you mean. Thanks you very much!
